# How to index logs in elasticsearch on the basis of timestamp inside logstash config?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a single log file and want to index logs to elasticsearch on the basis of timestamp (e.g. gt > 24th oct ). How can I configure logstash for this? Since `ignore_older` field is for multiple files I can't use it.

Comment: Can you explain why ignore_older does not work for you? With the path and exclude options, you can chose the right files

Comment: yes, but i have a single file only, so wants to filter logs on that particular file with respect to Date that i am getting in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could accomplish something like this.  The easiest way depends on how your dates are represented.  For example, if your date in the file is in YYYY-MM-dd format, you can just do a string comparison like this:

```
    if ([timestamp] < '2015-01-01') {
            drop {}
    }
```

If it's not, your best bet is to add a new field with `@timestamp` as a string.  Just be aware that it'll be in GMT

```
    mutate {
            add_field => [ "mydate", "%{@timestamp}"]
    }
    if ([mydate] < '2015-01-01') {
            drop {}
    }
    mutate {
             remove_field => ["mydate"]
    }
```

Comment: yes this works for format YYYY-MM-dd but the format for my date is  [Tue Nov  8 11:47:28 2016] , so how to process string format date and filter the logs .

Comment: Parse the date using date filter and then use the @timestamp method above